# How to bind an image to Dropdownlist on IE browser? On Chrome, it works fine

Tags: javascript

I have written following block in my code for display image in combo box option.

```
var optionHolder = document.createElement('option');
optionHolder.value = "123";
optionHolder.text = "Demo Text";

optionHolder.style.cssText = image;
```

or

```
optionHolder.style.backgroundImage = image;
ComboBox.add(optionHolder);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"bind image to option tag"_? Can you edit your question and use a stacksnippet?

Comment: Any jsfiddle to give better explanation?

Comment: Most browsers don't support images in option tag, you should use a plugin for that or create your own markup/styling to simulate the select control.

Comment: there is a straight forward way of achieving this only in Firefox. for cross browsers there are plenty of plugins available. there is no specific workaround for IE